# Creating MySQL table from data in another table

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have a form with a series of 21 checkboxes. When the form is submitted, each checkbox is recorded as a 1 or 0 in a field in a MySQL table. This is all fine as far as it goes -- the owner of the site can retrieve this information on a page that shows which checkboxes have been checked for each user, which is all she needs for her purposes.

However, for other purposes, I need a table that records sets of data consisting of the id of each user and a number corresponding to each checkbox that that user checked. So, for example, if I have two users with ids 145 and 146 and the first (145) checks checkboxes 5, 7 and 12 and the second (146) checks checkboxes 1, 9 and 17, I need to record the following in another MySQL table:

```
| userid | ckboxnum |
---------------------
|  145   |     5    |
---------------------
|  145   |     7    |
---------------------
|  145   |    12    |
---------------------
|  146   |     1    |
---------------------
|  146   |     9    |
---------------------
|  146   |    17    |
---------------------
```

I could insert this data into the second table as the data is entered, but that adds a complication since the user can go back later and change the checkboxes. However, there is a deadline beyond which users cannot make changes. So it might make more sense to use the data in the first table to create the second table after the deadline, thereby avoiding the change issue.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to do this.

Comment: If your first table already holds the info which user checked which checkboxes – then what for would you need a second table? Sounds like you want to store the same data twice.

Comment: As @CBroe says you already have the data all you require is a different view.

Comment: I need the second table to build a (geographic) map, which combines the data in that table with the data in a couple of other tables. The map code allows filtering the points on the map according to the data in the second table. I agree it's a different view of the same data, just trying to figure the best way to get from the current view to the view I showed in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You need something similar view:

```
create view checkedonly as select userid, ckboxnum from checkbox_results where checked=1
```

And you can use this view as you planned to use the second table.